# Pointers and references error in C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference, matching

i get those errors when i try to compile a simple AVL tree program :

```
no matching function for call to A::max(A*&, A*&)
candidates are: int A::max(A&, A&)
request for member 'levels' in 'b', wich is of non-class type 'A*'
```

Here is the method that cause the problems :

```
void A::simpleLeftRotation(A & tree){
   A* b = tree.leftNode;
   tree.leftNode = b->RightNode;
   b->rightNode = &tree;
   tree.levels = 1 + max(tree.leftNode, tree.rightNode); // Problem 1
   b.levels = 1 + max(b.rightNode, tree); // Problem 2
   tree = b;       
}
```

And here are my class Members :

```
A* righNode;
A* leftNode;
int levels;
int element;
```

In the line :

```
b.levels = 1 + max(b.rightNode, tree);
```

if i use the -> insted of the point operator i get :

```
no matching function for call to A::max(A*&, A&)
candidates are: int A::max(A&, A&)
```

I dont know what i am doing wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: Thank you every one. Mysticial's answer is the most complete one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you didn't show us the declarations for all the types, I suspect this will fix the problem:

```
tree.levels = 1 + max(*(tree.leftNode), *(tree.rightNode));
b.levels = 1 + max(*(b.rightNode), tree);
```

Originally, you were passing pointers in when the `max` function expects references. Hence, a type mismatch leading to your errors. So you need to dereference your pointers as shown.

Comment: That's the complete answer i was aiming for. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should call `max` as:

```
max(*(tree.leftNode), *(tree.rightNode));

max(*(b.rightNode), tree);
```

Because the type of `leftNode` and `rightNode` is `A*`. The type of `tree` is `A`, so that is okay.

I would suggest you to change the parameter types of  `max` from `A&` to `A*`, as it would make the code a bit more clean.

Answer (score 1):

You need to dereference your pointers:

```
tree.levels = 1 + max(tree.leftNode, tree.rightNode);
```

You're attempting to pass pointers to a method that takes references as parameters. Do:

```
tree.levels = 1 + max( *(tree.leftNode), *(tree.rightNode) );
```